# What is wrong with my coffeescript translation of this JS?

Tags: coffeescript

Trying to improve my Coffeescript skills, so thought I'd covert this [jcrop demo](http://jcrop.org/demos/circle). However it's not working as expect. Specifically, the `redraw` function does not appear to be being called.

This works fine.

```
// Create a new Selection object extended from Selection
  var CircleSel = function(){ };

  // Set the custom selection's prototype object to be an instance
  // of the built-in Selection object
  CircleSel.prototype = new $.Jcrop.component.Selection();

  // Then we can continue extending it
  $.extend(CircleSel.prototype,{
    zoomscale: 1,
    attach: function(){
      this.frame.css({
        background: 'url(' + $('#target')[0].src.replace('750','750') + ')'
      });
    },
    positionBg: function(b){
      var midx = ( b.x + b.x2 ) / 2;
      var midy = ( b.y + b.y2 ) / 2;
      var ox = (-midx*this.zoomscale)+(b.w/2);
      var oy = (-midy*this.zoomscale)+(b.h/2);
      //this.frame.css({ backgroundPosition: ox+'px '+oy+'px' });
      this.frame.css({ backgroundPosition: -(b.x+1)+'px '+(-b.y-1)+'px' });
    },
    redraw: function(b){

      // Call original update() method first, with arguments
      $.Jcrop.component.Selection.prototype.redraw.call(this,b);

      this.positionBg(this.last);
      return this;
    },
    prototype: $.Jcrop.component.Selection.prototype
  });
```

But when I try to write this in Coffescript it fails

```
  CircleSel.prototype = new ($.Jcrop.component.Selection)

  $.extend CircleSel.prototype,
    zoomscale: 1
    attach: ->
      @frame.css background: 'url(' + $('#target')[0].src.replace('750', '750') + ')'
      return
    positionBg: (b) ->
      midx = (b.x + b.x2) / 2
      midy = (b.y + b.y2) / 2
      ox = -midx * @zoomscale + b.w / 2
      oy = -midy * @zoomscale + b.h / 2
      @frame.css backgroundPosition: -(b.x + 1) + 'px ' + -b.y - 1 + 'px'
      return
# this redraw function is not being called, everything else appears to work fine
    redraw: (b) ->
      $.Jcrop.component.Selection::redraw.call this, b
      @positionBg @last
      this
    prototype: $.Jcrop.component.Selection.prototype
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I don't see a definition of `CircleSel` anywhere. This might be easier to sort out with a functional demo on jsfiddle.net or similar.

Comment: thanks @muistooshort, I've finally made some progress with this. Two issues were causing problems. Adding parentheses to the backgroundPosition line `(-b.y - 1)+'px'` has solved one of these problems. The other is a result of functions being called on objects before the have completed rendering. I've created a new question, which I hope I've manged to explain clearly, at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218979/how-to-ensure-a-dom-object-has-rendered-before-calling-a-function-on-it

Comment: You could also say `backgroundPosition: "#{-b.x - 1)}px #{-b.y - 1}px"` if you find string interpolation easier to read than all those `+`s.