# How to ensure a DOM object has rendered before calling a function on it?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I'm using a jquery plugin ([jcrop](http://jcrop.org/)) which has one of its options set by the the value of a DOM element.

```
jQuery(function($){
  var CircleSel = function(){ };
  CircleSel.prototype = new $.Jcrop.component.Selection();
  $.extend(CircleSel.prototype,{
    zoomscale: $('#img_container').data('zoomscale'),
    # more stuff......
```

The problem is that '#img_container' is only created by jcrop once the page has loaded, and so zoomscale is being set to null. I can't think of any other way to get this value — I need the `#img_container`'s zoomscale, which is calculated from the width, to ensure crops are correctly positioned from the original image.

I guess I need to either delay the `CircleSel` function, or enforce a strict order to ensure rendering of `#img_container` completes before `CircleSel` is run.

This is stretching my limited javascript knowledge, but I'd like to learn how to approach this with jquery/ javascript. Appreciate any advice or pointers to the necessary functions or examples.

Comment: _"to ensure rendering of `#img_container` completes before CircleSel is run."_ Have you tried using `.ready()` handler ?

Comment: this is part of a function that is called on `document.ready`. But there are two parts to the function. One initializes the plugin ` $('#DOMobject').Jcrop` while CircleSel extends the plugin. The initialization functions add `#img_container` to the page. How do I use `.ready()` so that CircleSel is run when Jcrop completes? Grateful for a code example if possible?

Comment: How do you determine when `jcrop` is fully initialized ?

Comment: The problem is not that '#img_container' was not present. It is present thats why you can init that plugin on that DOM. The problem is it's data attribute 'zoomscale' is not computed when you needed it.

Comment: From the document i saw there is optional callback to it's init api

 $('#target').Jcrop(options, callback);

Comment: I have created a codepen with more detail. line 20 of the js is the sticking point. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNwmda